# Do I apply the univariate or the multivariate version of the Newton-Raphson iterative method to this equation?

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

The equation in question is  $f(x) = x^4 - 4x - 2$ and I want to minimise the function. Regardless of whether it is ideal or not to use Newton-Raphson, which one would I use?

Sorry if this is a silly question, I'm new to ML and my math foundation is a little shaky.

Comment: You have a univariate function, no?

Comment: so you want to apply newton-raphson to the derivative f' to find the min of f?

Comment: @cineel yes that's what I want to do.

Comment: @angryavian: how do you know this is a univariate function? what would a multivariate function look like?

Answer (score 1):

As **angryavian** said in the comments, you have a **univariate** function, since your function consists only a single variable, which is $x$.

A **multivariate** function would be a function which consists more than one variables, such as $f(x,y) = x^2 - y^2 + xy$ for example.

Thus, you need to use the **univariate** version of N-R for your minimization problem.

By the way, from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Univariate): *"In mathematics, a univariate object is an expression, equation, function or polynomial involving only one variable. Objects involving more than one variable are multivariate."*

Comment: Thank you, that makes it much clearer. Is Newton-Raphson likely to be successful in this case? Plotting the equation shows that it is a convex function with two roots, one positive and one negative, with one stationary point in between the two. My guess is that depending on the magnitude of the weight used in each iterative update it may work or it may get stuck/face a zero division error. If the starting point is close to one of the roots it may find one of them (local convergence). Is this correct?

Comment: @S_J The derivative is a cubic polynomial with one real root, monotonous everywhere. In such cases the Newton method tends to converge globally without any problems.

Comment: @LutzLehmann so even though the actual function isn't monotonic, because its first derivative is, it will converge? Does globally converge mean it will find both roots?

Comment: @S_J There is no "two roots" to be found in this task, there is exactly one minimum for this convex function. Please state it in the question text if you want to find more of the "interesting" points of this function.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I got confused between NR for root-finding and NR for optimization